# Teamcity: Determine if worker is running job

Tags: teamcity, chef-infra

I have a chef script that sets up our teamcity workers.

I would like this script to cancel itself in case there is a teamcity job running, because, naturally, this would be dangerous.

I'm mainly looking for a bash solution, because teamcity isn't designed to work with chef.

My code looks something like this at this point.  I'm concerned that simply stopping the teamcity agent is dangerous if a job is already running.

```
execute "Stop Teamcity Agent" do
  user "root"
  # Code that might break ongoing teamcity jobs
  command "#{home}/BuildAgent/bin/agent.sh stop"
end

# More code that could break ongoing teamcity jobs

execute "Start Teamcity Agent" do
  user "root"
  command "#{home}/BuildAgent/bin/agent.sh start"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a ps and then grep for the agent names (if you have a common pattern). In case you find any matching agents you can either  kill them all(pkill -9 -f

You can also modify your script to only bring up the agents that are not running and leave out the agents that are already running( This depends on what exactly you want your chef script to do)

Comment: I did this manually while a script was running.  I noticed no difference in our process list when the teamcity job was running as opposed to when it was not.

I don't want to determine if the teamcity _agent_ is running - I want to determine whether or not the teamcity agent is running any jobs.  I intend to just cancel the chef script if teamcity is running a job.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if a build is running through the API. First create a token via **My Settings & Tools | Access Tokens** and give it at least the **View build runtime parameters and data** permission. Then you can `curl` the builds API like so:

```
curl -s --header "Authorization: Bearer <token>" localhost:8111/app/rest/builds?locator=running:true | grep "<builds count=\"0\""
```